# Graph API: Is there a sub category list limit?

Tags: database, facebook-graph-api

I started using the Graph API from Facebook. If you fetch pages, you get a main category, like

```
"category": "Club",
```

And sub categories, like:

```
  "category_list": [
    {
      "id": "176139629103647", 
      "name": "Dance Club"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "191478144212980", 
      "name": "Night Club"
    }
  ],
```

I'm currently struggling to create a database of this data, because I don't know how many sub categories a page can have. Either I create a separate table, which creates a new entry for each sub category, or in my table with the other information, I create multiple fields for every sub category, if there is a limit.

I did not found more information on their documentation page. Any suggestions how to find that out? Or any tips for a database structure?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple fields for every sub category would be a very bad idea, even if there would be a max limit. Even if there would be a max limit right now, you can never be sure it stays that way. Always try to normalize your database - assuming you are using MySQL. You would not even have that problem with MongoDB, for example :) - because you could just put the whole entry in the document as it is.

Comment: So you would suggest using a NoSQL database rather than a relational based one (such as MySQL)? (which I'm currently using)

Comment: depends on what you want to do in general, in general nosql is faster and easier to handle because you can store json directly.